# cookie not saved in the browser before the next request

Tags: php, cookies

I have been working on a login system in php. The thing works pretty well but I have 1 funny Behavior I cant get rid of. Basically if I perform many quick refreshes (hitting f5 like crazy) I get logged out.

This is because the system relies on the server refreshing a cookie in the browser every time a request is issued. I have the feeling that when refreshing very quickly, the request N+1 is issued before the cookie returned by the request N has been saved in the browser. This leads to a misalignment of the info in the provided cookie and the info expected by the server.

In fact if I hit f5 regularly, say once a second, the authenticated state is maintained and everything works fine.

Any1 has ever had a similar problem? As far as u know, is the process saving cookies executed in a different thread in the browser? That would explain my problem I guess.

gracias hombres

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a problem of saving the cookie, but a problem of aborting the request.

- browser sends request to server
- server handles request, prepares new cookie, invalidates old cookie
- you hit F5
- browser aborts request, issues new request with old cookie
- server sends response including new coo--
- server receives new request with old, invalid cookie

And yeah, that happens. To avoid this causing problems you might want to allow the last *two* cookies to be reused, but that requires some manual session juggling.

Comment: cool mate. yeah it makes a lotta sense to me. Also 1 solution would be refreshing the auth cookie only if 1 minute has passed from the last refresh. What u reckon?

Comment: @nourdine That would be subject to the same problem. It makes it a little less likely, but doesn't cure the problem.